# Can someone check if this solution for this probability problem is correct?

Tags: probability, statistics

[image]

I was thinking it should be $C^{15}_{60} + C^{15}_{45} + C^{15}_{30} + C^{15}_{15}$

Comment: The solution in the picture is correct.

Comment: It depends what you mean by different assignments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem you're having is that you're using addition where you should be multiplying. I'll assume you're logic is that we choose 15 from the 60 for the first group, then 15 from the leftover 45 for the second, etc.  But this is a situation where you multiply because by saying "choose 15 from the 60 *then* choose 15 from the leftover 45..." What we really mean is that there are $\binom{45}{15}$ choices that follow for *each* of the $\binom{60}{15}$.

The other problem is that you aren't dividing by the $4!$.  The reason this is necessary is because the order of the teams doesn't matter, only which groups of players end up together. So, imagine you're picking the players that go to teams A, B, C, D.  By the logic from before, the are $\binom{60}{15}\binom{45}{15}\binom{30}{15}\binom{15}{15}$ ways to do it. However, which team is named what doesn't matter. So each way you could relabel the teams still counts as the same outcome for that assignment of players. Since the number of ways to rename/reorder the teams is 4!, we divide by that to undo all the double-counting.